# How to implement the client using this example

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using this [Return list in WCF](http://forums.asp.net/post/4651962.aspx) example but I cannot implemment the client code correctly. The example works. I want the list transfered on the client side.

My code so far:

```
List<Person> aPerson = new List<Person>()
Person y = new Person()'
aPerson.Add(y.id, y.name, y.adress, y.salary, y.country)
```

This is the server:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    public string Id;
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string salary;
    public string country;

    public Person()
    { }

    public Person(string _id, string _name, string _address, string _salary, string _country)
    {
        Id = _id;
        name = _name;
        address = _address;
        salary = _salary;
        country = _country;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Idps
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string nameps
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string addressps
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string salaryps
    {
        get { return salary; }
        set { salary = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string countryps
    {
        get { return country; }
        set { country = value; }
    }

}


public List <Person> GetData(string Id)
    {

        //Create a List of Person objects
        List<Person>employeelist =new List<Person>();

        employeelist.Add(new Person("10", "name", "myAdress", "1000", "myCountry");

        }

        //Return the list that contains Person objects
        return employeelist;

    }
```

I don't know how to implement the client side using the code above. The server returns the list and I want to store the list local at the client.

Comment: Your posted code shows absolutely nothing to do with returning a `List<T>` from a WCF service to the client.  Please post the **relevant** code.

Comment: The code above is at the client side. I'm creating a new list which will be populated by person objects which will have attributes as id, name, adress, salary, country. The person objects will be send by the server.

Comment: So why you post irrelevant code? I think you should rethink and reformulate your question, because now it is mess. Or at least look at [full example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734712(v=vs.100).aspx) first to get an idea how server client sides should be made. For now I am voting to close because question is unclear.

Comment: The questions was updated. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are best off walking through a full end-to-end example as found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx which should help you get up to speed with WCF.

However, as a jump start... I assume that in your interface you have decorated your method `GetData` with the `[OperationContract]` attribute?

Then on the client you need to reference the WCF Service. When adding the service you should click on the **Advanced** button in the lower-left corner of the dialog. Change the **Collection type** drop-down from `System.Array` to 
`System.Collections.Generic.List`.

Finally, your client should be able to call the service with some code like this:

```
public void SampleClientCode()
{
    using (var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
    {
        List<Person> results = client.GetData("12345");

        // Now do something with the data... Example
        string firstPersonsName = results.First().nameps;
    }
}
```

*NOTE: Your property naming convention in your `Person` class is not very good and should be revised.*

Comment: I have already tried that. I receive this error:


`Cannot implicitly convert type 'WcfServiceLibrary1.Person[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WcfServiceLibrary1.Person>'`

Comment: That is because when you added the reference you can say you want collections to be returned as generic list. By default they are arrays. I will update answer.

Comment: Damn, I read about adding the list reference somewhere as I was searching the internet.

Comment: @g90 I have added additional steps on how to do that for completeness.

Comment: This was the problem from the beginning! Thank you very much and i apologise for my bad formated question.